# How is list size dynamic?

Tags: c#, list, collections

I am curious as to how a list is dynamic and how it works behind the scenes and found it surprisingly hard to find anything in a quick google search so I thought this would be a good question. I'm thinking the list class stores data in an array but is it as simple as just recreating the array behind the scenes so the list user doesn't have to worry about it? If so, how often does it do this and when?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/09/09/experiment-list-lt-t-gt-internals-and-performance-when-adding-new-elements.aspx

Comment: I don't really understand the question.   A list is dynamic because that makes it easier to work with.   If you loaded, say, database results into an array, you'd spend 80% of your time writing plumbing code to manage that array.

Comment: @Curt Sorry, maybe the wording of the title isn't clear enough but if you read the actual question I'm asking how it is actually made to be dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List<T>` is just a wrapper around an array.  It keeps track of how many items have been added and what its capacity is.  If you try to add a new item beyond its capacity, it allocates a new array (of double the size of the original), copies everything over to it, then adds the new item to the array.

To get information about how a particular .Net class works, it's easy enough to get the .Net sourcecode and see how the class is implemented.  You can download it directly from Microsoft as Eric notes, or use decompiler which I've found easier/quicker to do for a quick look around (I personally use [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)).  Also note that MS has only released up through .Net 2.0, so seeing .Net 3.5+ code will need the decompiler.

Comment: Good answer, thank you. Interesting that it doubles in size, this is what I was wondering about. I will definitely check out the decompiler as well.

Comment: @awhitehouse104: The source code is also available from Microsoft FYI. You don't have to decompile it. Search for "Shared Source CLI" for details.